# Necessary and sufficient conditions for $f(x) \geq g(x)$ over interval from higher-order-derivatives.

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

Consider two real-valued functions $f, g$ over some interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$. I would like to know whether one can give simple necessary and sufficient conditions for $f(x) \geq g(x), \forall x \in [a,b]$ in terms of higher order-derivatives of $f$ and $g$. For instance, if you give me a list of all derivatives (including the function values) of the two function evaluated at some point on the interval, can I infer whether one graph lies above the other? There should be something that can be said via Taylor expanding the two functions but I can't find anything anywhere.

Comment: How would one detect vertical displacements with derivatives?

Comment: @Jose27, thanks. As I said, I would include the function values at the point as the "zeroth" derivatives. This "anchors" the function with respect to vertical displacements, no?

Comment: If you know $f^{(n)}(x_0)$ for some $x_0$ and all $n\in \mathbb{N}$, you can't say anything outside of the singleton $\{ x_0\}$. Consider $f_\pm(x)= \pm e^{-1/x^2}$ and $g(x)=0$ with $x_0=0$. On the other hand, if $f,g$ are analytic maybe something can be said.